# Appending chunked data to a variable gives an unexpected result

Tags: node.js, json, undefined, stringify, minio

I'm trying to add a JSON object which comes from `minio` file to MongoDB

But the data is like `undefined[{"field":"value"}]`

Here is my code:

```
var miniData
minioClient.getObject(fileData.type,fileData.userId+fileData.fileName,function(err,exData) {
    exData.on('data', async function (chunck) {               
        miniData += chunck;
    });
    exData.on('end',async function () {
        console.log(miniData)
        excelDb.create({ excelArray:miniData}) 
    });
});
```

and in MongoDB document it is stored as:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0b02b9775cee50051b2547"),
    "excelArray" : "undefined[{\"FIELD\":\"VALUE\"}
}
```

I want a JSON array in my document.

Comment: Paste the Error. 'Data is like undefined' doesn't mean anything!

Comment: Actually there is no error just i didnt like that result.It is unusable

Comment: Then write the response how it is supposed to be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `miniData` an initial value. If you won't do that, it is implicitly `undefined` and `undefined` plus string makes the `undefined` to bo converted to a word. See the examples below.

Without initializing the variable:

```js
var miniData;

miniData += 'a string';

console.log(miniData);
```

With an initial value:

```js
var miniData = '';

miniData += 'a string';

console.log(miniData);
```

So in your code it should be like this:

```
var miniData = ''; // initialize the variable with an empty string
minioClient.getObject(fileData.type,fileData.userId+fileData.fileName,function(err,exData) {
    exData.on('data', async function (chunck) {               
            miniData += chunck;
    });
    exData.on('end',async function () {
        console.log(miniData)
        excelDb.create({ excelArray:miniData}) 
    });
});
```

And if you want to have an actual array in the MongoDB document, you need to `JSON.parse` the `miniData` before inserting so the **final** solution should be like this:

```
var miniData = ''; // initialize the variable with an empty string
minioClient.getObject(fileData.type,fileData.userId+fileData.fileName,function(err,exData) {
    exData.on('data', async function (chunck) {               
            miniData += chunck;
    });
    exData.on('end',async function () {
        console.log(miniData)
        excelDb.create({ excelArray: JSON.parse(miniData)}) 
    });
});
```